# How third party applications accessing data while Instagram API shuts down?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

My access to Instagram API denied but I wonder how other third party websites accessing data like http://picbear.online. This website shows data for each user like followers, media, following etc.

My Question is if Instagram API shuts down then how these third-party application accessing users data.